# WP: Enqueue JS at very end of the loading site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a script, which changes div's placement a little. To work fine, it must be loaded at very end of the page loading - it's because my WP page have few different plugins, some of them uses the js to display content on page, and moving that content is what I want to achieve.

I've tried to put 999999 priority to add_action parameter, also tried to cheat with js function settimeout, but that's not the point - it must work every time, and my "solutions" didn't provide me that. There was always some linked scripts which were loaded later than mine, timeout works sometimes, but only sometimes...

Plugins which i think could collide: Woocommerce, Easy FancyBox, Instagram Feed.

Thx for help!

[EDIT]

So, i need to change this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="destination">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="origin">
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="destination">
            <div class="origin">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js code is:

```
var from = document.getElementsByClassName("origin");
jQuery("window").on("load",function(){
    jQuery.each(from, function(i, el) {
        jQuery(el.parentNode.parentNode).find(jQuery(".destination"))[0].appendChild(el);
    });
});
```

And only what i need is to load it up last after all js files.

Also, the function which works sometimes looks that:

```
var from = document.getElementsByClassName("origin");
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.each(from, function(i, el) {
        jQuery(el.parentNode.parentNode).find(jQuery(".destination"))[0].appendChild(el);
    });
},1);
```

Comment: Sounds like something that should rather be solved using CSS.

Comment: Maybe if there's any way to put one div into another after page loaded with CSS

Comment: Maybe there is a way to achieve what you want ... if you could actually describe what that is. Please go read [ask], and how to create [mcve] (if helpful for understanding or to experiment with in this specific instance.)

Comment: Edited my question :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `$( document ).ready(function() {` try to use `$( window ).on( "load", function() {`

Comment: Tried, doesn't work, but i'm not sure. Look at my code on the top.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating things ... especially by mixing vanilla JS DOM methods and jQuery so much.

```
$('.destination').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().appendTo($(this));
})
```

For each `.destination` element, go up to its parent (`.bar` - could explicitly pass that selector into parent(), but there seems no need here), grab the next sibling of that - and append it to the current destination element we started with, done.

https://jsfiddle.net/a04fp226/

That wrapped into document ready should do the trick - provided the elements exist at that point already. If not, you need to figure out the correct time when to run this - that would depend on how those elements are created in the first place. If another script adds them on document ready, it becomes about execution order.